# Check if input is not empty and exist - PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, web, isset

I need to check if several tags are "not empty". For this I use:

```
<input id="designation" type="text" size="12" disabled="disabled" />
```

Then, I need to place several of `<input ...>` in a table. All of this is created in HTML. I need to check if any of the tags are empty.

```
$erreurs = array();
// Check if the tag is not empty

if((empty($_POST['CodetERDF']))) {
    $erreurs[] = 'Veuillez renseigner le codet ERDF.';

    echo 'Veuillez renseigner le codet ERDF.';
}`
```

But my code doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why.

Comment: Where does `CodetERDF` come from?

Comment: @JonStirling In future, the page will be go on database to fill cropdown. So CodetERDF come from database.

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with anything. Do you have an input in your form with the `name` attribute of `CodetERDF`?

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do? describe properly.
Is it form submit?
Where is name attribute?
Use `<input id="designation" name="CodetERDF" type="text" size="12" />`

Comment: @JonStirling Yes, here : `<TH>
    <FORM>
     <SELECT id="ERDF" size="1">
      <!--<OPTION>3700002
      <OPTION>3700143
      <OPTION>3700144
      <OPTION>3700302
      <OPTION>3700312
      -->
      <!-- Test de remplissage lsite déroulante depuis base SQL -->
     </SELECT>
    </FORM>
   </TH>`

Comment: @McNavy In what you've pasted, do you see the string `CodetERDF`? Becuase I don't. I don't see a `name` attribute either.

Comment: @JonStirling It's a field in my BDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled inputs are not posted to the server, so they will never appear in `$_POST`.

The same applies to inputs without a `name` attribute as it is the `name` attribute that defines they key in `$_POST`.

Alternatives are making them `readonly`, `hidden` or simply setting the value in a session variable / keeping it on the server.

Comment: Oh.. Okay @jeroen. So I need to do what for correct my mistakes please?

Comment: @McNavy Ummmmm, `Alternatives are making them readonly, hidden or simply setting the value in a session variable / keeping it on the server`. And add the correct `name` attributes to form elements...

Comment: remove the `disabled = "disabled"` and replace with `readonly`

Comment: yeah @McNavy.. but make sure you name all your field properly before you call it in your php

Comment: @dass . Thanks. But a few input needs to be filled automatically as another input. Would you please answer?

Comment: @dass And he exist any solution for avoid the user to complete the input

Comment: i didnt understand your question.. please ask again precisely

Comment: I am looking for a solution to avoid modifying an <input> by the user. This is <input> will not be modified by the user but filled automatically.

Comment: filled automatically means?? using php code?? or will be filled by yourself?? you can use `value` attribute to insert value for the field

Comment: so, add the value attribute to your input field like `value="<?php echo yourvalue; ?>"`

Comment: @McNavy If the user is not supposed to change it, don't use an input...

Comment: @jeroen So, I need what? Sorry, but I'm again a student, so I don't know a lot of other tag for an entry filed in HTML ..